# Cannot use recur inside map

Tags: clojure

I would like to call function recursively up to 10000 times but it is clearly to big for my stack. That is why I tried use loop/recur but I faced an issue. My function ends like this:

```
...
(max (map #(recur %) subcollection))
```

It seems recur won't work for deep first search.
So what is "state-of-art" of doing long DFS (longer than stack can handle)

Thank you.

Comment: `map` takes a f and produces f(n) for every element in N, what do you expect `#(recur %)` to do ? maybe illustrate you problem f with a single argument first ? `( #(recur %) 3)` as an example is wrong - regardless of `map` or any other HOF; In other words - please explain `I would like to call function recursively up to 10000 times` more

Comment: ok. let say i have a tree with depth > 10000.  And I want to do DFS. how can I do this?

Comment: have a look at [`clojure.walk/postwalk`](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.walk/postwalk/). Doc: `Performs a depth-first, post-order traversal of form.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recur` is to code a tail recursion as the JVM does not support automatic tail recursion optimisation.

Tail recursion means that calling the recursive function needs to be the last thing that has to be done. If that is the case, you don't have to return to the calling method and therefore you don't have to keep a stackframe for it.

What you wrote needs to do more things after the recursive function returns. Therefore the stack-frame needs to be preserved.

The “state of art” to get this working is that you have to reformulate your recursive function to become a tail recursive function. Normally this can be achieved best by using an accumulator that you pass with your recursive function calls.